# Is whisky wine?

Tags: meaning

I have talked about “is whisky wine?” with a Chinese guy.
To my knowledge, wine is sth made from grapes, but whisky is not.
However, in his concept, wine is equal to alcoholic drink. Rum is wine, whisky is wine. 
I just want to ask, in the concept of English speaker, if I say “this bottle of wine is whisky” do you think it is a correct sentence ?

Comment: Most significantly, per any reasonable definition, whiskey is a distilled liquor, while wine is not distilled.  This is one of the most basic divisions in alcoholic beverages.

Comment: There's an old saying "Never mix the grain and the grape". In other words don't drink whiskey and wine in the same session. I guess that says it all.

Comment: This is not a question about the English language, the answer is the same for all languages. I cannot imagine any Italian or French speaker asserting that wine and whisky are synonymous or that rum is "wine". Your friend is a non-native speaker, do not pay any attention to their nonsense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the distinction between wine and whisky. There's nothing "English" about it.

Comment: @BillJ - Actually, beer is from grain, and is not whiskey.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's a question about the _English_ meaning of the word 'wine'. The OP is not sure if it means 'any kind of alcoholic drink' or is it means 'alcoholic drink fermented with wine'. Of course, this is closable as 'no research'.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, but the OP asked whisk(e)y and wine.  The old saying holds true. Don't be pedantic.

Comment: @BillJ - Don't be pedantic???  We'll have to shut down EL&U!!!

Comment: I have seen this also.  "Wine" and "whisky" are the same word in Chinese.  On the other hand, I have found this rationalization among some Musims:  The Quran forbids "wine", therefore other alcoholic drinks are okay.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The answer would **not** be the same for all languages. Many languages do not have separate words for distilled vs fermented beverages.

Comment: @GEdgar I don't know Chinese, so I'll take your word for it. But I'm curious to know if any alcoholic beverage in China is identified by the same word.

Comment: @James Random, I'll be curious to know if these languages, where alcohol is legal, keep the original term on the label or if they translate the contents of a Jack Daniel's, a Chianti or a Guinness with the same term. It seems quite absurd and until now I would have said impossible.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In some cases (eg. Japanese) they use loan words (*wain*, *uisukii*) or they use adjectives/phrases to describe the drink (*budou shu* = "alcoholic drink made from grapes" etc. )

Answer (score 2):

Without further qualification, [*wine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine) is fermented from grape juice while [*fruit wine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_wine) uses other fruit: cherries, elderberries, dandelions, even pineapple and bananas.

[*Whisky/whiskey*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whisky) is distilled from fermented grain mash. Both wine and whisky are aged in wooden barrels, but only whisky is distilled. [*Fortified wines*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortified_wine) such as sherry or port add grape spirit (brandy) at the end of the wine fermentation process (sherry), or before the process is complete (port), which prevents further sugar turning to alcohol.

Rum is made from sugar cane, and vodka, at least traditionally, from potatoes. Thus they are not types of whisky.

One reason your Chinese friend might be confused is an alcoholic drink popular in Korea, Japan, and China which is called *plum wine* in English. This “wine” is basically alcohol infused with fruit flavor and begins with already distilled spirits. The closest Western equivalent would be fruit brandy, though the process is different.

Comment: There is also _soju_, which is often drunk straight with food...